# Как поменять слова местами в переменной (PHP)

Tags: php

```
$currency
```

Всегда содержит два слова
temp1 temp2

Как сделать?
temp2 temp1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850603/swap-two-words-in-a-string-php

Answer (score 5):

Общий случай реверса слов разделенных пробелами:

```
<?php
$str = 'Мама мыла раму';
$str = implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $str)));
var_dump($str);
```

Результат:

```
string(26) "раму мыла Мама"
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfdc3aecd4f03ae2c4bafd7f8b0589bda3d9008e

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант с наглядно именованными переменными:

```
$currency = 'temp1 temp2';
list($temp1, $temp2) = explode(' ', $currency);
$currency = "$temp2 $temp1";

echo $currency; // temp2 temp1
```

Answer (score -1):

Разбейте строку по разделителю, и склеивайте.

```
$str = "temp1 temp2";
$str = explode(' ', $str);
$str_new = $str[1] . ' ' . $str[0];
```